# How to find and replace an external text file from r

Tags: r

I have created a file in r with some results.

This file needs to be referenced in another text file (which is a configuration file for another program.

I would like to find out therefore how to find and replace in an external text file from R. Specifically to find the text

```
#CustomFile1Here
file=""
```

So far I have (in R)

```
#Create the file
write.table(mydata,"blabla.circos.txt",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep="\t")

#Assign the filename to be inserted into the config file
filename1="blabla.circos.txt"

#insert the filename just created into the config file at the line (and between the "" in
##CustomFile1Here
##file=""
system(paste("grep ^#CustomFile1Here\nfile='",filename1))
```

At the moment when I run this everything just stalls. Is it because of the double quotes or is the whole thing incorrect?

Comment: If `mydata` is actually a table, you can simply read the whole file as a data.frame and find the column/row named `filename1`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. I want to read the filename and paththat the dataframe has been written to, into another external text file.

Comment: In other words. What is `mydata`? A list? A data.frame?

Comment: mydata is a dataframe

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought `mydata` and `filename1` were on the same file.